# Infinite recursion when instantiating object

Tags: oop, recursion

I have two classes, Class A and Class B.

Class A has an ArrayList of objects Class B.

Each Class B object has an attribute that stores a Class A object.

So when I create a Class A object, it populates the ArrayList of objects Class B. Each object Class B creates an object Class A (same as the one that is being populated), which creates an ArrayList of objects Class B... and so on.

What should I do to avoid this infinite recursion?

Comment: showing the how you "populates the ArrayList of objects Class B" and "creates an object Class A" would be useful. I assume its done in the constructors for these classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This should fix infinite recursion:** (Java assumed)

```
Class A {

  private ArrayList<B> list = new ArrayList<B>();
  A(){ 
    while(someCondition) {
      list.add(new B(this));
    }
  }
}

Class B {

  private A attribute;
  B(A inRef){ 
    attribute = inRef;
  }
}
```

Note that `B`'s `attribute` field is not assigned using `new` but by passing in a reference to `A`. By not using `new` we do not create a new instance of the `A` class and avoid recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you misunderstand difference between class (as type) and object.

`...So when I create a Class A object, it populates the ArrayList of objects Class B. Each object Class B creates an object Class A (same as the one that is being populated)...`
 -- not exact `same` as object, but same as class. Each object `B` stores objects of class `A`.
And once created object `A` is might not be the same object like `A->B->A`.

But if you want to have reference to parent object `A` from object `B`, you may use references (for example. you want to use its public methods and so on). So in this case you must not create new entities of object `A` in `B`, but, when you create your object `B` -- in constructor of `B` you must use as parameter reference to parent object `A`.

In C++ this trick is fairly common.